# Flutter AnimatedCrossFade messes up widget formatting

Tags: android, flutter, dart, layout, animatedcrossfade

I'm trying to create a smooth animation using the **AnimatedCrossFade** widget but I noticed 2 problems:

##### Button dimension changes and expands during animation.

The desired outcome is that both buttons match the parent's width and that the color and text changes transition smoothly, but here's what happens.

- Without **AnimatedCrossFade**, **Button 1** looks like this:

[image: Button 1 without AnimatedCrossFade]

- If I wrap it inside an **AnimatedCrossFade** widget, **Button 1** looks like this:

[image: Button 1 with AnimatedCrossFade]

- While the transition is happening, It looks like this:

[image: Button Transitions]

##### TextField with InputDecoration stroke becomes thinner

I have multiple **TextField** widgets that I want to use in the page but some need to be animated in. The problem is that when I put a **TextField** inside an **AnimatedCrossFade** widget, the bottom line becomes thinner making the layout look horrible. Here's a comparison of how a **TextField** looks inside an **AnimatedCrossFade** (top) and outside of it (bottom).

[image: TextField differences]

- This is how the layout looks after animation.

[image: Layout before]

- But it should look like this.

[image: Layout after]

This code sample should be enough to recreate what I'm trying to explain.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 60),
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text(_isExpanded ? "Collapse" : "Expand"),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
              });
            },
          ),
          AnimatedCrossFade(
            crossFadeState: _isExpanded
                ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            firstChild: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Text",
              ),
            ),
            secondChild: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Text",
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedCrossFade(
            crossFadeState: !_isExpanded
                ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            firstChild: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Button 1"),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            secondChild: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Button 2"),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add an image that should be after animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is what you want?

[image: result]

I think to handle this case, you need to use `layoutBuilder` of `AnimatedCrossFade`
if you click on `layoutBuilder` you can find details.

**Updated**
`wrap with padding to solve TextFiledFormat`, for more you can use `decoration`.

[image]

***To use max width*** i used like this

```
  AnimatedCrossFade(
            crossFadeState: _isExpanded
                ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            firstChild: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
              child: TextField(
                key: ValueKey("text1"),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Text1",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            secondChild: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
            child: TextField(
              key: ValueKey("text2"),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Text",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
            child: AnimatedCrossFade(
              crossFadeState: !_isExpanded
                  ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                  : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              layoutBuilder:
                  (topChild, topChildKey, bottomChild, bottomChildKey) {
                return topChild;
              },
              secondChild: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Button 2"),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              firstChild: ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Button 1"),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

---

***To get default size of button wrapped with Center inside layoutBuilder***

```
  layoutBuilder:
                (topChild, topChildKey, bottomChild, bottomChildKey) {
              return topChild;
            },
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves the problem for the button but I still can't figure out how to fix the TextField.

Comment: i wrapped with padding for better view, check updated answer

Comment: Thank you. That works. You don't even need to apply the padding to the whole AnimatedCrossFade, you can apply it to the TextField. I also noticed that putting the Buttons inside a container with infinite width also works and makes the transition more smooth.